# смена диапазона для random

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

как можно установить новый диапазон для distribution после установки в конструкторе или нужно все таки создавать новую переменную?

```
#include <random>
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,6);
```

Comment: Можете просто присвоить новое распределение старому, либо использовать функцию-член `param`.

Comment: @Croessmah 1) param почему не хочет принимать --distribution.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(1, 6)); 
2) а присваивание да работает, обманулся тем что не видел operator= в спецификациях

Comment: @Ildar ему объект нужен

Comment: @Ildar `param` хочет объект `param_type`, а не распределение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете просто обновить его используя метод param - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/param и отдать туда новый класс с новым распределением!

```
      dis.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type(7, 10));
```

Вот пример кода :

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    dis.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type(7, 10));

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```